# Parallel programming in python (nested loop)

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I have the following code and since it is very slow for larger l i am asking myself if there is an easy possibility to parallelize this loop. I also tried to parallize it by my own, but because I never did it before I am not able to manage it. I would be happy if you can help me out

```
print('Create 2.0L%.3frec%.3f.npy' % (l, r))
for x1 in range(a**l):
    for x2 in range(a**l):
        for x3 in range(a**l):
            f11 = 0
            if numpy.ndarray.sum(numpy.absolute(numpy.subtract(ws[x1:x1+1], ws[x2:x2+1]))) == 0:
                f11 += 1
            if numpy.ndarray.sum(numpy.absolute(numpy.subtract(ws[x1:x1+1], ws[x3:x3+1]))) == 0:
                f11 += 1
            re[x1][x2][x3] = 1.0*r/(a**l-2)*(numpy.product(numpy.absolute(numpy.subtract((2*ws[x1:x1+1]+ws[x2:x2+1]+ws[x3:x3+1]), 2)))-f11)

            cv1 = numpy.ndarray.sum(numpy.absolute(numpy.subtract(ws[x1:x1+1], ws[x2:x2+1])))
            cv2 = numpy.ndarray.sum(numpy.absolute(numpy.subtract(ws[x1:x1+1], ws[x3:x3+1])))
            c2 = 0
            if cv1 == 0:
                c2 += 1
            if cv2 == 0:
                c2 += 1
            c2 *= 1.0*(1-r)/2
            re[x1][x2][x3] += c2
numpy.save('2.0L%.3frec%.3f' % (l, r), re)
print('Saved 2.0L%.3frec%.3f.npy' % (l, r))
```

So since all entries of re are independent of the others, there should be a way. I guess I would be helped if I know a solution how to parllize a python program like:

```
for x1 in range(a):
    for x2 in range(a):
        for x3 in range(a):
            re[x1][x2][x3] = 5*3
```

Comment: You need to give more background.  What is the format of your data?  Can you explain what the loop is supposed to do?

Comment: Have a look at the multiprocessing library

Comment: Won't `ws[x1:x1+1]` essentially mean `ws[x1]` and similarly for others?

Comment: Don't you mean vectorize?

Comment: @Divakar: You are right.. I just made it more complicated...

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to calculate, but I'll give it a shot. For your latter question, you can do this as follows:

```
re = np.empty([a]*3) 
x = np.indices([a]*3)
re[x] = 5*3
```

You can vectorize your code as follows:

```
x = np.indices([a**l]*3)
cv1 = (ws[x[0]] == ws[x[1]]).astype(float)
cv2 = (ws[x[0]] == ws[x[2]]).astype(float)
f11 = cv1 + cv2
re = 1.0*r/(a**l-2)*(np.absolute(2*ws[x[0]]+ws[x[1]]+ws[x[2]]-2)-f11)    
re += f11*1.0*(1-r)/2
```

(I removed superfluous sums and products, and used the == operator to check for equal values, and used that c2 and f11 are the same thing). In theory this should do the same as your code.

Comment: That looks really nice, I will try it out soon :)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/2.3.1.py", line 113, in <module>
    wp[:,0] = numpy.tensordot(numpy.tensordot(re, wp[:,0], axes=1), wp[:,0], axes=1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1246, in tensordot
    if as_[axes_a[k]] != bs[axes_b[k]]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range         I am getting this error now. Apparently the re tensor has now a different size?

Comment: It's shape should still be the same as before, namely `(a**l,a**l,a**l)`.

Comment: Does it have to be re[x] ?

Comment: I tried it on an example `a=2`,`l=3`, `r=0.3` and `ws = np.ones(a**l)`. There it returns the same answer as your code (namely all entries of re are 0.7).

Comment: Maybe next time specify `ws` and the expected output so it is easier to test. Most of the ideas for vectorizing your code are there, so I leave the rest to you.

Comment: You are right..I will do it better next time. The problem is solved now here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081288/performance-issue-in-python-with-nested-loop   Nevertheless, thank you for the effort!