# How to optimize a nested for loop, looping over json data to extract values of certain keys in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, for-loop, python-multiprocessing

I am reading log files in my python code which contains some nested json data. I have a nested for loop containing 4 for-loops from which values of certain keys are extracted and appended to a dataframe.

The nested for-loop is taking too much time and I saw from other answers that multiprocessing is the way to go for nested for-loops but did not find an example for json data.

What is the best approach for this ? Below is my code to extract data from log files and into dataframes. `recommendation_list` is a list of json objects.

```
    for recommendation in recommendation_list:
    if recommendation['type'] == "httpRequest":
        session_id = recommendation['query'].split('sessionId=')[1].split('&')[0]
        category_id = recommendation['query'].split('categoryId=')[1].split('&')[0]
    if recommendation['type'] == "httpResponse":
        recommendation_count = recommendation_count + 1
        user_id = recommendation['userId']
        time_stamp = recommendation['ts']
        event_date = time_stamp.split("T")[0]
        time = time_stamp.split("T")[-1]
        try:
            product_list = json.loads(recommendation['body'])['products']
        except:
            product_list = []
        if len(product_list) > 0:
            for product in product_list:
                product_id = product["id"]
                if 'recommendationMeta' in product:
                    data_frame = data_frame.append({
                        "transaction_id": last_id,
                        "user_id": user_id,
                        "session_id": session_id,
                        "category_id": category_id,
                        "product_id": product_id,
                        "date": event_date,
                        "time": time[0:12],
                        "event": "recommendation",
                        "ab_bucket": "B",
                        "recommendation_count": recommendation_count,
                    }, ignore_index=True)

                    for learning_unit in product['recommendationMeta']:
                        lu_name = learning_unit['lu']
                        lu_value = learning_unit['value']
                        recommendation_mode = learning_unit['recommendationMode']
                        prod_def1 = products[(products["product_id"] == product_id) &
                                             (products["lu_value"].str.lower() == lu_value)]
                        if len(prod_def1) != 0:
                            product_list = prod_def1.to_dict('records')

                            for product_id in product_list:
                                category = categories[(categories["category_def_id"] == product_id["category_def_id"]) &
                                                      (categories["lu_name"].str.lower() == lu_name)]
                                if len(category) != 0:
                                    product_def_id = product_id['product_def_id']
                                    lu_df = lu_df.append({
                                        "lu_data_id": lu_id,
                                        "product_def_id": product_def_id,
                                        "transaction_id": last_id,
                                        "rec_mode": recommendation_mode,
                                    }, ignore_index=True)
                                    lu_id = lu_id+1
                    last_id = last_id + 1
```

I figure that the innermost for-loop executes most number of times and decided to use multiprocessing for it.

I replaced

```
                                for product_id in product_list:
                                category = categories[(categories["category_def_id"] == product_id["category_def_id"]) &
                                                      (categories["lu_name"].str.lower() == lu_name)]
                                if len(category) != 0:
                                    product_def_id = product_id['product_def_id']
                                    lu_df = lu_df.append({
                                        "lu_data_id": lu_id,
                                        "product_def_id": product_def_id,
                                        "transaction_id": last_id,
                                        "rec_mode": recommendation_mode,
                                    }, ignore_index=True)
                                    lu_id = lu_id+1
```

with this...

```
for product_id in product_list:
      pool = Pool()  # Create a multiprocessing Pool
      data = pool.starmap(create_lu_data, [last_id, categories, recommendation_mode,
      lu_name, lu_df, lu_id, product_id])
      lu_id = lu_id + 1
      p.close()
      print(data)
```

where `create_lu_data` is

```
def create_lu_data(last_id, categories, recommendation_mode, lu_name, lu_df, lu_id, product_id):

category = categories[(categories["category_def_id"] == product_id["category_def_id"]) &
                      (categories["lu_name"].str.lower() == lu_name)]
if len(category) != 0:
    product_def_id = product_id['product_def_id']
    lu_df = lu_df.append({
        "lu_data_id": lu_id,
        "product_def_id": product_def_id,
        "transaction_id": last_id,
        "rec_mode": recommendation_mode,
        }, ignore_index=True)
return lu_df
```

I didn't get any errors, but the output dataframe has several times the expected number of rows.

Comment: Can you please add the the stack trace? i.e. what line of code did that error come from.

Comment: @Paul, I have updated the question. I fixed the error but the output is wrong.

Comment: Pool can be used to parallel-execute same logic with different inputs. I don't see what input ranges are handled here. You are creating the Pools with single task in a loop if I understand correctly.